# Parsing a JSON string to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to parse this JSON string:

`var string = '{"DataSerialized":{"DocumentElement":{"NAME_LIST":"FIELD_1":"VALUE_1","FIELD_2":"VALUE2","FIELD_3":"VALUE_3"}}}}';`

how a JSON object how this:

```
{
    "DataSerialized":{
        "DocumentElement":{
            "NAME_LIST":{
                "FIELD_1":"VALUE_1",
                "FIELD_2":"VALUE2",
                "FIELD_3":"VALUE_3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For that, I tried with `jQuery.parseJSON(string)` but the result is wrong:

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 60 of the JSON data`

I think that it's a problem with quotes, but I don't know what's wrong exactly

Thanks in advance

SOLUTION:
`{` after `NAME_LIST`

`var string = '{"DataSerialized":{"DocumentElement":{"NAME_LIST":{"FIELD_1":"VALUE_1","FIELD_2":"VALUE2","FIELD_3":"VALUE_3"}}}}';`

Comment: JSON uses double not single quotes. http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: your JSON is invalid, you have an extra closing curly brace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one missing a `{` after NAME_LIST and you should use `"` not `'`

Comment: Actually there is one missing `{` after `NAME_LIST`. Would still be invalid after your changes.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, `{` after `NAME_LIST`. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This string:

```
var string = "{'DataSerialized':{'DocumentElement':
    {'NAME_LIST':'FIELD_1':'VALUE_1','FIELD_2':'VALUE2','FIELD_3':'VALUE_3'}}}}";
```

Has one too many closing braces.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$.parseJSON` you should use " instead of '

if you have any problem with json format. Try [jsonformatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: Even that it won't be valid, try to use Python json.load("hisjson") it won't work, Json uses double quotes !

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong JSON format, you miss one { after name list. There is correct example

```
var string = '{"DataSerialized":{"DocumentElement":{"NAME_LIST":{"FIELD_1":"VALUE_1","FIELD_2":"VALUE2","FIELD_3":"VALUE_3"}}}}';
JSON.parse(string);
```

Try to run it on browser dev console and then you will see correct object